# Platform Specific Service Causes an Exception - MvvmCross, Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am developing an application in which I need to use platform specific services. I referred so many stuff in the internet and couldn't find a way to get this to work. Even the MvvmCross documentation has not been updated I guess.

My platform specific service is to pop up dialogs in each platform in their native appearances.

Since I am new to MvvmCross I couldn't think of a way to make this work. Any help would be highly appreciated.

*Note:* MvvmCross version is 6.4.2

**IPlatformSpecificDialogs.cs in Core/Common Project**

```
public interface IPlatformSpecificDialogs
{
    void Alert(string message, string title, string okButtonText);
}
```

**IOSDialogs.cs in iOS Project**

```
public class IOSDialogs : IPlatformSpecificDialogs
{
    public IOSDialogs()
    {
    }

    public void Alert(string message, string title, string okButtonText)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("worked");
    }
}
```

**Setup.cs in iOS Project**

```
public class Setup : MvxIosSetup<App>
{
    public Setup() : base()
    {
    }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        return App.Instance;
    }

    protected override void InitializeLastChance()
    {
        base.InitializeLastChance();
        Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterSingleton<IPlatformSpecificDialogs>(() => new IOSDialogs());
    }
}
```

**MyView.cs in iOS Project**

```
[MvxFromStoryboard("Main")]
[MvxModalPresentation(WrapInNavigationController = false)]
public partial class MyView : BaseView<MyViewModel>
{
    public MyView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
    }

    protected override void BindControllers()
    {
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyView, MyViewModel>();
        set.Bind(AlertButton).To(vm => vm.AlertCommand);
        set.Apply();
    }
}
```

**MyViewModel.cs in Core/Common Project**

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly IPlatformSpecificDialogs _platformSpecificDialogs;

    public MyViewModel(IPlatformSpecificDialogs platformSpecificDialogs) : base()
    {
        _platformSpecificDialogs = platformSpecificDialogs;
    }

    public override Task Initialize()
    {
        return base.Initialize();
    }

    public IMvxCommand AlertCommand => new MvxCommand(PopupAlert);
    private void PopupAlert()
    {
        _platformSpecificDialogs.Alert("Title","Messege", "OK");
    }
}
```

**Exception I get when I navigate to MyView**

[image]

**This is the Inner Exception Messege**

> Failed to resolve parameter for parameter platformSpecificDialogs of
>   type IPlatformSpecificDialogs when creating
>   MyProject.Core.ViewModels.MyViewModel. You may pass it as an argument.

**This is the Inner Exception StackTrace**

> at MvvmCross.IoC.MvxIoCContainer.TryResolveParameter (System.Type
>   type, System.Reflection.ParameterInfo parameterInfo, System.Object&
>   parameterValue) [0x00020] in
>   D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\IoC\MvxIoCContainer.cs:686    at
>   MvvmCross.IoC.MvxIoCContainer.GetIoCParameterValues (System.Type type,
>   System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo selectedConstructor,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary'2[TKey,TValue] arguments)
>   [0x0003a] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\IoC\MvxIoCContainer.cs:646    at
>   MvvmCross.IoC.MvxIoCContainer.IoCConstruct (System.Type type,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary'2[TKey,TValue] arguments)
>   [0x0002b] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\IoC\MvxIoCContainer.cs:416    at
>   MvvmCross.IoC.MvxIoCContainer.IoCConstruct (System.Type type)
>   [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\IoC\MvxIoCContainer.cs:363    at
>   MvvmCross.IoC.MvxIoCProvider.IoCConstruct (System.Type type) [0x00000]
>   in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\IoC\MvxIoCProvider.cs:149    at
>   MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxDefaultViewModelLocator.Load (System.Type
>   viewModelType, MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle parameterValues,
>   MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState,
>   MvvmCross.Navigation.EventArguments.IMvxNavigateEventArgs
>   navigationArgs) [0x00000] in
>   D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\ViewModels\MvxDefaultViewModelLocator.cs:56

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to resolve parameter for parameter platformSpecificDialogs of
>   type IPlatformSpecificDialogs when creating
>   MyProject.Core.ViewModels.MyViewModel. You may pass it as an argument.

The exception you are experiencing is due to a timing issue. To resolve it rather than placing the platform-specific dialogs registration in `InitializeLastChance()` place it in `InitializeFirstChance()`

> Since I am new to MVVMCross I couldn't think of a way to make this
>   work. Any help would be highly appreciated.

In terms of native dialogs I would suggest having a look at [ACR User Dialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) you can either use the cross-platform library directly or use it for inspiration in creating your own custom implementation.

---

### Explanation

MvvmCross startup life cycle consists of a two-phase ([Documentation link](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/getting-started/mvvmcross-overview#how-an-mvvmcross-application-starts)).

1. **InitializePrimary** - Runs on the main sync context (aka main thread). Initializes the IoC, Logging mechanism and other core parts.
2. **InitializeSecondary** - Runs on the background (never on the main thread). Constructs some other platform services like bindings, the `App` class and calls `Initialize` on it. It finally registers Views / ViewModels lookups.

The initialized methods calls are as follows ([Documentation link](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/advanced/customizing-using-App-and-Setup#setupcs))

```
    // InitializePrimary 
    InitializeFirstChance();                // Earliest possible hook
    InitializeDebugServices();
    InitializePlatformServices();
    InitializeSettings();
    InitializeSingletonCache();

    // InitializeSecondary 
    PerformBootstrapActions();
    InitializeStringToTypeParser();
    InitializeViewModelFramework();
    var pluginManager = InitializePluginFramework();
    InitializeApp(pluginManager);           // App start up trigger here
    InitialiseViewModelTypeFinder();
    InitializeViewsContainer();
    InitiaiseViewDispatcher();
    InitializeViewLookup();
    InitialiseCommandCollectionBuilder();
    InitializeNavigationSerializer();
    InitializeInpcInterception();
    InitializeLastChance();                 // Last possible hook (async process)
```

You can see here `InitializeFirstChance()` occurs as the first hook within the `InitializePrimary` phase while  `InitializeLastChance()` occurs as the last hook in the 
`InitializeSecondary`phase. The issue arises where within `InitializeSecondary` the method `InitializeApp(pluginManager)` triggers the startup sequence for the app. This triggers the creation of your first view model which in your current case has a dependency on a service that has not yet been registered against the IoC provider. Leading to the exception showing that it can not resolve the parameter.

`InitializeLastChance()` usage would be fine if you don't have an immediate requirement for the service. ***Note***, that `InitializePlatformServices()` is currently marked as deprecated in favour of `InitializeFirstChance()` ([Documenation link](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/inversion-of-control-ioc#how-do-i-use-ioc-when-i-need-different-implementations-on-different-platforms)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Plac3Hold3r. But no luck. I still get same exception.

Comment: @GMHSJ is anything else happening in your constructor for `SupportViewModel`?

Comment: No thats exactly as in the question. I use IMvxNavigationService to navigate to MyView / MyViewModel.

Comment: When I append "Service" to both class and interface names, and then put IOSDialogsService class into the same folder which contains IPlatformSpecificDialogsService interface in core project it works. It is because service registration in Initialize() in App class I guess. I don't understand why is doesn't work in platform specific way.

Comment: Did you fix that? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Expressingx unfortunately, not yet :(

Comment: @GMHSJ could you perhaps place a reproducible sample on GitHub that I could take a look at?